# tomcat8 running but gui is not getting opened

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I have deployed a application using elastic beanstalk and it got deployed with the status OK. Also corresponding to that one ec2 instance got also created and I have been able to login to the server from Linux terminal. From the Linux terminal I saw the tomcat is running but instead of that I am not able to open the tomcat gui (Tomcat8 is installed bydefault from elastic beanstalk). I have tried restarting and changing the inbound rules also but still I am not able to open the tomcat8 gui from my browser. My connector port is by default 8080 . Please tell me what's the exact issue so that I can move to elastic beanstalk.

Comment: I've found when using elastic beanstalk apps don't behave if their not hosted on port 5000, cant remember the specific reason it was something to do with them using nginx for the underlying

Comment: heres a good explanation of why https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=686324,  if you'd like to change the default listener to port 8080 Anssi@AWS provides an answer